# Converting a list of list to a string with a delimiter of choice in the place of comma

Tags: python, for-loop, join

Here is a sample list of lists:

```
sample = [[6594, 3084, 6956, 3429], [6401, 1154, 6693, 1436], [6463, 712, 6754, 1015]]
```

Now I have a requirement that there are to be no commas in the string, so inside a sub-list, I have to replace the comma with ":" and the comma between the two lists will have to be replaced with "|".

Finally, the output will look like this:

```
"6594: 3084: 6956: 3429|6401: 1154: 6693: 1436|6463: 712: 6754: 1015"
```

I tried using the join method by first converting the list of lists to string:

```
sample = str([[6594, 3084, 6956, 3429], [6401, 1154, 6693, 1436], [6463, 712, 6754, 1015]])
final_result = "|".join(sample)
```

This yielded me the output string:

```
'[6594, 3084, 6956, 3429]|[6401, 1154, 6693, 1436]|[6463, 712, 6754, 1015]'
```

So this is half-way through.
But then I cannot again apply the join method as each number is a string and I will get a funny-looking output.

I understand that writing a nested for loop will solve this issue, but is there a more elegant approach like using "join" or "map" or any such similar methods?

Note: The output has to be in the string format as shown above.

Comment: is list always contains four elemets?

Comment: `"|".join([": ".join([str(x) for x in i]) for i in sample])`

Comment: this is probably the most inefficient way but, `str(sample).replace('], [', '|').replace(',', ':')[2:-2]`

Comment: yes the sub-list always has four elements. But the variable "sample" can contain any number of lists.

Answer (score 10):

I like this method

```
"|".join(": ".join(map(str, x)) for x in array)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
'|'.join([': '.join(list(map(str, item))) for item in sample])
```

This will work fine for you.

1. Iterate over sublists
2. Convert the sublist elements to string using map and join them with a ':'
3. Now join the whole resulting list with "|"

Answer (score 2):

````
sample = [[6594, 3084, 6956, 3429], [6401, 1154, 6693, 1436], [6463, 712, 6754, 1015]]
"|".join(": ".join(map(str, element)) for element in sample )```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
In [29]: '|'.join(': '.join(str(j) for j in i) for i in sample)
Out[29]: '6594: 3084: 6956: 3429|6401: 1154: 6693: 1436|6463: 712: 6754: 1015'
```